# Is this way to access mongodb in node.js acceptable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new to programming and trying to experiment a bit, still struggling with the best way to access mongoDB from within my code. I've seen a few posts here on stack overflow but they more or less all require that the code required to load mongo is included in each and every .js file. I would like to avoid that in order to keep the code for accessing my DB in only one file.

Note that I am using the "mongo-factory" module.

Would the code below be acceptable?

I've created what I would call a "producer" of database objects, database.js

```
var mongoFactory = require('mongo-factory');

function Database(close,callback) {

    mongoFactory.getConnection(<connection string>).then(function (database) {
        callback(database.db(<db name>));
        if(close) database.close();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}

module.exports = Database;
```

Then when I want to access the database from any of my files I could do the below, avoiding to introduce db-specific parameters and the mongo-factory requirement in here:

```
var Database = require('./database');

var callback_actOnDatabase = function (db) {

    db.collection..... do something here

};

var d = new Database(false, callback_actOnDatabase);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of mongo-factoy use mongoose module to connect the database,model declaration also we dont intalise the db parameters again,please go through the link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose